# Display text above list if list is empty? (SharePoint 2007)

Tags: sharepoint, list, sharepoint-2007

I have seen a SharePoint list (Custom list) where text shows up, whenever a list is empty (only for some views). E.g. to inform users of the guidelines for the list usage.

How can this be implemented?

Ok with javascript/jquery solution

Comment: I would actually like to acvcept both answers but thats not possible I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing the message that appears for document libraries using jQuery:

```
// Change text for uploading documents
var docUploadRegexp = new RegExp();
docUploadRegexp.compile('(.+document\\slibrary\\.)(\\s+To\\screate.+\\.)', 'g');
$('table[class*=ms-listviewtable] > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td[class*=ms-vb]:first-child').each(function(i, n) {
    var matches = $(n).text().match(docUploadRegexp);
    if (matches) {
        $(n).html(RegExp.$1);
    }
});
```

(Any suggestions on how to make it nicer **very** welcome - made community wiki.)

To make this work on a custom list, replace `(.+document\\slibrary\\.)` with `(.+list\\.)`.

Comment: Does this work for a custom list? Then intention is that in 2-3 views for a normal custom list a text should be displayed informing the users on how to use the list/content, only if the list is empty (sorry, not too much at home with jQuery yet ;o)

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the list controls on your view pages into Data Views using SharePoint Designer. 
Data Views allow you to set a text when there are no items found:

[image]

Comment: How du you get that dialog? (what selection)

Comment: You need to Open the Page in SharePoint Designer and You will see a DataView WebPart, Right click Propertied.

Comment: Your solution is good and easy to use but I'll accept the other solution because it's more flexible regarding what you can do with the output. Thx for the answer anyways!